# Bug with <kbd> tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The `<kbd>` tags overlap if you don't put an extra line between them.  See below:

<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.

Comment: Fix looks good @Jin